# Mysql returns different result for 2 queries with similar where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I enter the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
WHERE `tournament` = 'Super 15'
AND `round` = '13'
```

I get back:

[image]

YET when I insert:

```
SELECT events.event_id,events.tournament, events.team1, events.team2,events.round,
       events.event_date, events.venue, picks.pick
FROM  events 
INNER JOIN picks ON  events.event_id = picks.event_id
where
events.tournament="Super 15" AND events.round="13"
```

I GET:

[image]

TABLE 1:

[image]

TABLE 2:

[image]

ANY idea why im getting different results back for the two queries with similar `WHERE` clause

Comment: Your queries are not similar at all.  The second has a `join`, for instance.  Presumably, not rows match in the two tables (that also match the `where` conditions).

Comment: second query has a join with pick may be there will not be any match to retrieve data according to that

Comment: @OP: what is the output for `select * from picks where event_id between 1800 and 1806` ???

Comment: picks.event_id is not matching any value of events.event_id so no result will be shown because you are using inner join

Comment: @babar so which join should I use, left outter?

Comment: Use an OUTER JOIN if you want a result regardless of the result of the join. `picks.*` elements will come out as null if there is no match.

Comment: Yes left outer join will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following query for same result :-

```
    SELECT events.event_id,events.tournament, events.team1, events.team2,events.round,
       events.event_date, events.venue, picks.pick
FROM  events 
LEFT JOIN picks ON  events.event_id = picks.event_id
where
events.tournament="Super 15" AND events.round="13"
```

Comment: but then I get pick from PICKS tables value as NULL

Comment: becouse events.event_id not exists in picks.event_id so return null picks tables value